# how created a color conditioning in column chart with upper and lower bounds in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I would like to know if it is possible to have color conditioning in a column chart. For example, when the column chart is below the line, it changes to red, when it is above the line, it change to green and when it is in between the 2 lines is yellow.

The picture below is the graph, but colors are not right.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZh0b.png]